# Why does this cause an infinite loop?

Tags: c++

I am working on a program where the user makes a selection by inputting an integer that is: 0, 1, 2 ,3.

The input part of the program should also reject inputs that are invalid such as a string or a character. So I made a loop which checks all the conditions, however, it seems that even when the correct integer is input, the loop continues running.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Mass massObj;
    double mass;
    int userChoice;
    
    cout << "Please make selection: ";
    while ((!(cin >> userChoice)) || userChoice != 1 || userChoice != 2 || userChoice != 3 || userChoice != 0) {
        cout << "Invalid. Try again." << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(123, '\n');
        cout << "Please make selection: ";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `userChoice == 1` is `userChoice != 2` true or false?

Comment: I highly recommend splitting up your `while` expressions.  The input should be in the `while` expression, however, the other expressions should be in an `if` statement, inside the `while` loop.

Comment: `userChoice != 1 || userChoice != 2 || userChoice != 3 || userChoice != 0` at least one of these is guaranteed to be true.  You probably want logical *and* not logical *or*.

Comment: Logical or works fine, if you test: `!(userChoice == 1 || userChoice == 2 || userChoice == 3 || userChoice == 0)`

Comment: You could also create a `std::set<int>` of acceptable values and check for membership in that set, or in this case just check that `userChoice < 0 || userChoice > 3`

Comment: The duplicate listed doesn't seem particularly applicable to the actual problem going on here.

Comment: Simply, `x != 1 || x != 2` is always true. There is no value of `x` for which this expression can _ever_ be false. If `x` is `1`, the right hand is true; if `x` is `2`, the left hand is true, and if `x` is any other value, both sides are true.

Comment: Or, in English, "x is neither A nor B" is not the same as "either x is not A, or x is not B".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your logic is that the following is always true. If any one condition is false, then the remaining three are true.

```
userChoice != 1 || userChoice != 2 || userChoice != 3 || userChoice != 0
```

You can achieve the desired effect by checking that *all* of these conditions are true, rather than *any* of them.

```
userChoice != 1 && userChoice != 2 && userChoice != 3 && userChoice != 0
```

Or by checking that `userChoice` is not any of them.

```
!(userChoice == 1 || userChoice == 2 || userChoice == 3 || userChoice == 0)
```

Given that the numbers are consecutive, you might also check:

```
userChoice < 0 || userChoice > 3
```

If the choices were not consecutive integers, you might also use a [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/) of acceptable options and check for membership.

```
std::set<int> acceptable_options { 1, 2, 3, 0 };
```

And then use the following condition to verify that the input choice is not valid.

```
acceptable_options.find(userChoice) == acceptable_options.end()
```

Answer (score 2):

As was pointed out in the comments, the condition in the while loop will always be true. You keep looping while any one of the following five conditions is true:

1. `!(cin >> userChoice)`
2. `userChoice != 1`
3. `userChoice != 2`
4. `userChoice != 3`
5. `userChoice != 0`

Option 1 handles the case when the user's entry could not be extracted from the stream. Perhaps the user entered a non-numeric string, for instance. Or maybe the user entered a floating-point value that begins with a period. In those cases, you want to keep looping.

When an integer is successfully extracted, however, at least three of the other options, and possibly all four, will be true. If a valid integer is entered, for example, it cannot be equal to `1`, and also be equal to `2`. So, when a valid integer is entered, either option 2 or option 3 (or both) will be true, and you will keep looping. Hence, the infinite loop.

##### Use a function to validate input

One easy way to get valid input from `std::cin`, is to write a function that handles both input and validation. Function `get_integer` (below) is such a function. It prompts the user to enter an integer, and keeps looping until a valid entry is made, which is then returned to the caller.

Optional arguments for `min` and `max` allow the caller to specify the range for valid entries.

- When parameter `min` is omitted, it defaults to `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`, which effectively means there is no lower limit.
- Similarly, when parameter `max` is omitted, it defaults to `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`, which means there is no upper limit.
- When an entry is out of range, a carefully crafted error message mentions `min` and `max` only when they are different from their default values.
- Parameters `ist` and `ost`, respectively, default to `std::cin` and `std::cout`. It is useful to have them as parameters in case you want to use other streams during testing.

Function `get_integer` also demonstrates the proper way to call `cin.ignore` when you want to discard *all* characters on a line in the input buffer:

```cpp
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

[CppReference explains](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore):

> "[Function`ignore`] extracts characters from the stream and discards them until any of the following conditions occurs:
>
> "count characters were extracted. This test is disabled in the special case when count equals `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`."
>
> ...

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int get_integer(
    std::string const& prompt,
    int const min = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
    int const max = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),
    std::istream& ist = std::cin,
    std::ostream& ost = std::cout)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        ost << prompt;
        int n{};
        if (!(ist >> n))
        {
            ist.clear();
            ist.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            ost << "Invalid entry. Please reenter.\n\n";
        }
        else if (n < min || n > max)
        {
            std::string msg{ 
                std::format("Invalid entry: {}. Please reenter.\n", n)
            };
            if (min > std::numeric_limits<int>::min() &&
                max < std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
                msg += std::format(
                    "Entries must be integers between {} and {}.", min, max);
            else if (min > std::numeric_limits<int>::min())
                msg += std::format("Entries must not be less than {}.", min);
            else if (max < std::numeric_limits<int>::max())
                msg += std::format("Entries must not be greater than {}.", max);
            ost << msg << "\n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            return n;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    char const* const menu
    {
        "MAIN MENU"
        "\n 1 Add"
        "\n 2 Modify"
        "\n 3 Delete"
        "\n"
        "\n Enter 0 to quit."
        "\n\n"
    };
    std::cout << menu;
    int userChoice{ get_integer("Choice? ", 0, 3) };
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

##### Output

Here's the output from a sample run:

```
MAIN MENU
 1 Add
 2 Modify
 3 Delete

 Enter 0 to quit.

Choice? Huh?
Invalid entry. Please reenter.

Choice? 4
Invalid entry: 4. Please reenter.
Entries must be integers between 0 and 3.

Choice? 0
```

Function `get_integer` can easily be templated to use types other than `int`.